# pandas: How can I do linear merge on two sorte dataframe with the same columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

For example,

```
df1

            x  y
2015-01-26  1  2
2015-03-24  3  4


df2

            x  y
2015-02-23  5  6
2015-04-27  7  8
```

I want to get

```
            x  y
2015-01-26  1  2
2015-02-23  5  6
2015-03-24  3  4
2015-04-27  7  8
```

How? I tried the `pd.merge`, it seems do not consider the same columns?

Also because `df1` and `df2` are already sorted, I do wish for a `O(n)` merge

**updated**

It seems

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer', sort=False, on=['x', 'y'])
```

will do the trick. I've set `sort=False`, will that be a `O(n)` solution?

Answer (score 1):

there's actually a method just for that:

```
df1.append(df2).sort_index()
```

this assumes that your indexes are of `dtype='datetime64[ns]'`

Comment: this is doing O(nlogn) sorting